# Xcode + Swift : How to Prevent a framework from compiling

Tags: swift, xcode, linker-flags

I have a situation where I need a framework added under "Link Binaries with Libraries" but it creates some issue for me, specifically on iOS 9 simulator.

```
It MUST be noted that this framework work without importing it programatically. In
other words it's a framework which if imported replaces the native code (the 
implementation is hidden from me). So basically even if you don't import this 
 framework or use any of it's API, it effects and alters the 
implementation of native APIs
```

Is there any way for me to prevent it from compiling by using some flags in build settings or with any preprocessor macros?

What I have tried so far:

```
1. Added this framework as optional under "Link binaries with libraries"
2. Under the build settings> Other linker flag> added the framework as a 
weak framework.
```

[image]

Both of the above points did NOT prevent it from compiling as I can see the issue happening on my iOS 9 simulator. If I remove the framework, everything works.